# C - Incompatible types in assignment - structs and character arrays

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Alright so the gist of my situation is that I'm stuck receiving an incompatibles types in assignment when trying to initialize my struct. I am fairly new to C and understanding pointers proves quite the challenge for me but I have looked at similar questions to this error and tried different fixes and have had no luck so far. If someone could fix this for me, you would be my hero.

```
struct Employee {

  char* name[100];
  int birth_year;
  int starting_year;
};

struct Employee* make_employee(char* name, int birth_year, int starting_year);

int main(){
//some main stuff code
}

struct Employee* make_employee(char* name, int birth_year, int starting_year){

struct Employee* newEmpl = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
 newEmpl->name = name;
 newEmpl->birth_year = birth_year;
 newEmpl->starting_year = starting_year;

  return newEmpl;
}
```

The assignment errors occurs on the name = name line. I don't know why.
Also if I switch that line with

```
strcpy(&(newEmpl->name), name);
```

I get:

warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer type

I've tried to find the problem for 2 hours, and no luck, thought I'd give a shot here.

Comment: `name` in your code is an array of pointers. Maybe you wanted to have `char name[100]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your structure, change

```
 char* name[100];   //an array of pointers to character
```

to

```
char name[100];     // a character array
```

Then, in your `make_employee()` function, instead of

```
 newEmpl->name = name;      //arrays cannot be assigned
```

use

```
strcpy(newEmpl->name, name);    // copy the contains of name to newEmpl->name
```

or

```
strncpy(newEmpl->name, name, 99);  // limit to 99 elements only + terminating null
```

Notes:

1. Please do not cast the return value of `malloc()` and family.
2. Please check for the success of `malloc()` and family before using the returned pointer.

Comment: even better than strcpy, please use `char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)` with a size argument of 100 so you don't overflow your string buffer.

Comment: @fearless_fool Thanks sir, but the size should be 99 to accommodate the terminating null. Updated. :-)

Comment: Hmm -- I disagree that it should be 99, but I've been known to be wrong.  Check the documentation for strncopy and make your case for why you think it should be 99.  :)

Comment: `strncpy` does not place a terminating null if one would not fit in the buffer, you have to write code to do that. Using `strncpy` is almost always a terrible idea.

Comment: I agree that a naked strncpy is a bad idea (but strcpy is worse!).  What you want is `strncpy(newEmpl->name, name, BUFLEN); newEmpl->name[BUFLEN-1] = '\0'` to force the last char to be a null.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* name[100];
```

is an array of pointers to `char` but:

```
char* name;
```

is a pointer to `char`.

Here:

```
newEmpl->name = name;
```

You are trying to assign a pointer to `char` to the array but you cannot in C assign a pointer to an array! In fact you cannot assign anything to an array in C.

Check you are using the correct types in your program. Are you sure you want to use `char *name[100];` and not `char name[100];` (an array of char)? Then to copy a string it, use `strcpy` or `strncpy` and not the `=` operator as you cannot assign something to an array.